# Unable to declare an ArrayList using Code on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, arraylist, collections, visual-studio-code

I'm using Code on OSX together with the .NET Core. While trying to create an ArrayList I'm getting an error that the namespace cannot be found.

The `System.Collections` is used already. While examining what is suggested from `System.Collections` I see that not all of the methods are listed as in the documentation.

What could be the problem? I installed the latest .NET Core from MS site.

Comment: For a starter use List<T> instead of ArrayList.

Comment: it doesn't matter, I can't reference this one either. I guess it's the Collections namespace, hence this question.

Comment: Is the assembly referenced?

Comment: Unless you referenced System.Collections.NonGeneric, those obsolete types won't appear.

Comment: @will no List<T> is in System.Collections.Generic

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna get by using List<T>, but it's still weird why I can't reference System.Collections.NonGeneric. I'm getting an error on the 'NonGeneric' that it's not found. I wonder what else I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the type because it is defined in a separate NuGet package,

http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.NonGeneric/

Note that only a few platforms are supported by this package, so for some monikers, you cannot reference it.

The recommended approach is to switch to the generic version of the collection types.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like System.Collections.NonGeneric is not supported in Mac. It didn't work for me even though I had that package installed. Looks like it's deprecated and also Microsoft suggests that to use Generic lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

Open you .csproj and add the following under

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.NonGeneric" Version="4.3.0">
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

in the terminal or command prompt, make sure you are on the same working directory as your project and run

```
# dotnet restore
```

You can now use it in your project